# Angular $watch not working?

Tags: angularjs

The code below only logs when the page is initially loaded. What's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="PageController">
            <p ng-bind="model.header"></p>
            <p>Value: <input ng-model="model.header" /></p>
        </div>
        <script>
            function PageController($scope) {
                $scope.model = {};
                $scope.model.header = 'Header';

                $scope.onModelChange = function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    console.log('model changed > newValue: ' + newValue + ' > oldValue: ' + oldValue);
                };

                $scope.$watch($scope.model, $scope.onModelChange, true);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first argument of $watch should be the scope property itself

```
$scope.$watch("model", $scope.onModelChange);
```

And you don't need to enable a deep watch on this property (third argument)

Comment: Thanks, got tricked by this line in an angular book: `$scope.$watch($scope.totalCart, calculateDiscount);`. Guess that works only for watching functions?

Comment: @SorinComanescu - isnt that book by Brad Green?. yeah that book has many mistakes.

Comment: Why is the deep watch not needed?

Answer (score 5):

As Florian F mentioned, the first argument is a string of the scope property you want to watch.

```
$scope.$watch("model", $scope.onModelChange, true);
```

But, as you are watching for changes to model.header, the 'deep' parameter does need to be set. If not true, the watch will only be triggered if the model object reference itself is updated.

Here's a plunkr showing both a shallow and deep watch where the shallow watch will not work because it's only watching the model object reference.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ejMc2pBjIFD9aX6PBsY1

Comment: Thanks, csquire. Interestingly, the plunker only gives 'deep model changed' messages.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  The shallow one is intended to not work because the watch is watching a property of the model.

Comment: No problem. Got it, replaced the 'model' with 'model.header' for the shallow one and it worked.